# ExtJS - custom toolbar with groupbutton title under icons

Tags: extjs

Can anyone have any idea how to make title text of groupbutton not above the icons but under in ExtJS? I was trying to do bbar to the groupbutton but the default td align is to left and I don't know how to change it by css? Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect by adding the following CSS to the button:

```
height: 64px;
background-position: top center;
padding-left: 0px
```

I this case, I have set the height of the button to be 64px. The will definitely distort the tool bar if you have a combination of default buttons and buttons with the above CSS.